# Html Code in PHP File - I am getting Error

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="text"  class="inputtext big" name="headline" 
value="<?php echo $row['headline'];?>" 
<?php if(isset($stop)){echo'disabled="disabled"'; } ?>  />
```

When i use the above code ....the textbox is not disabled...

I have set an stop variable there...

What could be the problem plus the input box closing tag `/>` is shown in different color...

Comment: Try `var_dump(isset($stop))` and report the output...

Comment: What is the generated html or error?

Comment: Hi praveen it says      boolean true

Comment: Isn't it `<input></input>` instead of `<input />`?

Comment: Actually it does not show any error but the end can you see the input type close tag( "/>" )..it show in different color.....

Comment: @poepje, <input /> is allowed.

Comment: @davidethell Yes, but I mean is it not supposed to be like that *here*.. since it's a textbox...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your generated HTML it is hard to say for sure, but it looks like you are ending up with markup that has no space between the value="" attribute and the disabled attribute. It also seems like you have no space between echo and 'disabled'.

Change your disabled logic to this:

```
<?php if(isset($stop)){echo ' disabled="disabled"'; } ?>  />
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the html that is output to your browser? Paste the source of what is being rendered.

Comment: Can you try teamviewer...As i am running it in local

Comment: If you are running it locally you can still view the source of your rendered page and paste the resulting html here.

Comment: <p>

      <label>Headline:</label><br/>

      <input type="text" name="headline" class="inputtext big" />

     </p>

Comment: Is that the output when $stop is true?

Comment: The output seems wrong because the value="" attribute is not even there.